# How to show/hide label in a different view when UISwitch isOn in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UISwitch component in my CreateSomethingViewController. This component is on a xib file.
In my SomethingTableViewCell, I have a label called existsLabel.
When I create my something, I can select as Existent (if I turn my UISwitch component on) or not (if Switch is off).

If my existsLabel was in my CreateSomethingViewController, I would do something like this:

```
@IBAction func changeSomethingExistence(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    let isExistent = sender.isOn
    existsLabel.isHidden = false

    if isExistent {
        existsLabel.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

How can I do this (show my existsLabel on my SomethingTableViewCell) when my UISwitch isOn? Using swift.

Comment: Do you have only one cell in your tableView? Or you have many cells but only want hide/show the label in a specific cell?

Comment: many cells! It is a list/cells of "Something" that I created in my CreateSomethingViewController. Some cells should show this label (if I marked the Switch component ON when I created that "Something")

Answer (score 0):

I think, you already knew the index or position of your updated objects. So We can reload only visible cells row after updating on particular objects to the index position of your cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? YourTableViewCell

    cell?.yourSwitch.isOn = yourList[indexPath.row].switchIsOne
    cell?.yourSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
    cell?.yourSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeSomethingExistence), for:UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    cell?.existsLabel.isHidden = !yourList[indexPath.row].switchIsOne

    return cell!
}
```

Here is your Switch update actions:

```
@objc func changeSomethingExistence(mySwitch: UISwitch) {
    yourList[mySwitch.tag].switchIsOne = mySwitch.isOn
    self.updateCell(indexRow: mySwitch.tag)
  }
```

Call this function from anywhere with your selected index and update the same.

```
func updateCell(indexRow: Int) {
    let updatedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexRow, section: 0)
    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [updatedIndexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.  Instead of hiding and showing a view, I set the background color of the cells.  The basic ideas are the same.

Essentially you need an object to store the value that the switch controls.  In this case I store that data in the same object that I used as the `UITableViewDataSource`.  When the switch is flipped, you tell that object to change the value.  It will broadcast the change to all the cells that are currently listening for the change.

There are lots of ways you could observe the change.  You could use the Target Action pattern, you could broadcast the change using the `NSNotificationCenter`.  You could use key/value observers, etc.  In this case the object holding the value has an `@Published` property and the cells subscribe to that property.

One critical thing to do is implement `prepareForReuse`. When a cell is scrolled off the view, it is put in a reuse queue.  Rather than create a new cell the system might hand you one out of the reuse buffer.  If it does that, you want to be sure the cell is listening to the right source of information for things that change dynamically.

You should be able to copy/paste this code into an iOS Playground:

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import Combine

class CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    var cancelBackgrounds : AnyCancellable?

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        cancelBackgrounds?.cancel()
        cancelBackgrounds = nil

        // ALWAYS call super... this can cause hard to identify bugs
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }

    func observeFancyBackground(dataSource: TableData) {
        // Set up to observe when the fanch Background value changes

        // If this cell was listening to someone else, stop listening to them
        // and start listeneing to the new guy.
        // This may not be necessary - its a safety check.
        cancelBackgrounds?.cancel()
        cancelBackgrounds = nil

        // Start listening to the new information source
        cancelBackgrounds = dataSource.$showFancyBackgrounds.sink(receiveValue: {
            isOn in
            self.setBackground(isOn)
        })
    }

    private func setBackground(_ showFancy: Bool) {
        if showFancy {
            self.backgroundConfiguration?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        } else {
            self.backgroundConfiguration?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
    }
}

class TableData : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    let tableData = (1...1000).map { "\(Int($0))" }
    @Published var showFancyBackgrounds = false

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
        cell.observeFancyBackground(dataSource: self)

        return cell
    }
}

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    let switchView = UISwitch()
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 320, height: 100), style: .plain)
    let tableData = TableData()

    // This is the action called when the switch is toggled.
    @objc func switchFlipped(sender: UISwitch) {
        tableData.showFancyBackgrounds = sender.isOn
    }

    // This just sets things up to be pretty.
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()

        switchView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchFlipped), for: .valueChanged)

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
        tableView.dataSource = tableData

        view.addSubview(switchView)
        view.addSubview(tableView)

        self.view = view

        let viewIDs = ["switch" : switchView,
                       "table" : tableView]

        let constraints = [
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
                withVisualFormat: "V:|-8-[switch]-[table]-|",
                options: [],
                metrics: nil,
                views: viewIDs),
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
                withVisualFormat: "|-[switch]-|",
                options: [],
                metrics: nil,
                views: viewIDs),
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
                withVisualFormat: "|-0-[table]-0-|",
                options: [],
                metrics: nil,
                views: viewIDs),
        ].flatMap { $0 }

        view.addConstraints(constraints)
    }
}

let myViewController = MyViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = myViewController
```

Comment: Note that this technique does not reload any rows or data.  Reloading requires a round trip to the data source, it destroys views, layers, cells, relayout calculations, redrawing and flickering.  In short it can be expensive and can be visually disruptive.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by reloading the `tableView` when the `switch` is changed.

```
var isExistent: Bool
@IBAction func changeSomethingExistence(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    isExistent = sender.isOn
    //reload the table
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

In your `UITableViewDataSource` you can check which `cell.label` need to be hidden or not and accordingly hide/show the label of those cells

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //decide which cells needs to be hide/show based on the indexPath and switchValue
    //then you can call cell.existsLabel.isHidden = isExistent
}
```

Comment: Please don't reload the table view this way.  You are throwing away a lot of cached data and forcing the system to do a lot of calculation.

Comment: Sam, but my IBAction is on my SomethingViewController.swift and my IBOutlet of my existsLabel is on my SomethingTableViewCell.swift. If I try to call my existsLabel on my SomethingViewController.swift, like you said, it doesn't work. And that's exactly my question, how to pass this information between those two files/ViewControllers

Comment: @ScottThompson thanks for pointing out this. What would be the better approach here to update the cells?

Comment: @U23r you need to access the existsLabel as cell.existsLabel from UITableViewDataSource delegate method.

Comment: I'm trying to pull together an example.  The cells could monitor a signal - be it through key-value coding, or NSNotificationCenter, to note when the switch changes.  The you can also ask the tableView for all the visible cells and call a custom method on the cells to toggle the visibility.